# Angular - ngModelController missing $validators?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I've been looking at Angular docs here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

I'm trying to create my own input field validator using a custom directive. I've created a directive which seems identical to the one from the link above, only customized with my own validation function (6-digit password):

```
app.directive('password', function() {
   return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
           ctrl.$validators.password = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
               if (/^[0-9]{6}$/.test(viewValue)) {
                   return true;
               }

               return false;
           };
       }
   };
});
```

And when I run it, I get this error:

```
Error: ctrl.$validators is undefined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you use Angular 1.3?

Comment: 1.2.26, that's currently the latest stable version.

Comment: Then [`$validators`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Oh, ok. This explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$validators` only exist since version 1.3. Contrary to your comment the latest stable version is 1.3.0.

Comment: How come Google doesn't host it yet then? o.O

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs

Comment: [Google does host it](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js).

Comment: @Johannes `Today, after eight months of work, over two thousand commits, nineteen beta and six release candidates, we finally released AngularJS 1.3.0 superluminal-nudge`- Oct. 14th

Comment: Posted on http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ --> AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.3.x, tested with 1.4.7). 0.12.0 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.